# mcrypt warnings

Tags: php, mcrypt

I keep getting these warnings:

> Warning: mcrypt_generic_init(): mcrypt_generic_init(): 1 is not a
>   valid MCrypt resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 123, column 9.
>
> Warning: mdecrypt_generic(): mdecrypt_generic(): 1 is not a valid
>   MCrypt resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 124, column 9.
>
> Warning: mcrypt_generic_deinit(): mcrypt_generic_deinit(): 1 is not a
>   valid MCrypt resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 125, column 9.
>
> Warning: mcrypt_generic_init(): mcrypt_generic_init(): 1 is not a
>   valid MCrypt resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 100, column 9.
>
> Warning: mcrypt_generic(): mcrypt_generic(): 1 is not a valid MCrypt
>   resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 105, column 9.
>
> Warning: mcrypt_generic_deinit(): mcrypt_generic_deinit(): 1 is not a
>   valid MCrypt resource in C:\Users\dever\Desktop\web
>   code\HeloWorld\HeloWorld\Crypt.php on line 107, column 9.

Since it is a warning and the strings "seem" to be encrypted I have ignored it till now.  However it seems that the remote server I am working with is not liking the encrypted string and returning errors to me stating as much.

Here is the code generating those warnings:

```
    mcrypt_generic_init($this->_td, $this->_key, $iv);
    $data = mdecrypt_generic($this->_td, $data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->_td);
```

and

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(self::AES_BLOCK_SIZE, $random_source);
    $s = mcrypt_generic_init($this->_td, $this->_key, $iv);
    if( ($s < 0) || ($s === false))
        die( "Really an error" );
    $data = mcrypt_generic($this->_td, $data);
    $data = $iv.$data;
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->_td);
```

I have researched but could not find out what these warnings meen, if they are effecting the  encryption/decryption or what exactly is the problem?  Im pretty sure its not the code (as I have it working on a different server).

Comment: Apparently, `$this->_td` is not a valid MCrypt resource, exactly as the error message is telling you. You will have to show how you initialize `$this->_td`.

Comment: $this->_td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');  So the 1 stands for first parameter?

Comment: No, the `1` is what is getting passed in via the `$this->_td` variable.

Comment: Add a `var_dump($this->_td)` after your `mcrypt_module_open`; it should print something like `Resource id #15`, or `bool(false)` if `mcrypt_module_open` failed. _IF_ you get a resource id, add another `var_dump($this->_td)` right before you call `mcrypt_generic_init($this->_td, ...` and check if it shows the same resource id. If it is different, you're overwriting your `$this->_td` somewhere with garbage.

Comment: resource(3) of type (mcrypt) - after open | resource(3) of type (Unknown)  - before init call.  So I guess it is an overwrite but i dont see $this->_td = anywhere other then in the constructor with the call to mcrypt_module_open

Comment: @lanzz please post this as an answer and i will accept it.  If I reinitialize the _td variable prior to the calls shown above everything works.  So your comments are the problem.  just need to find out why or what is changing that variable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test I've performed, that reproduces the values you're seeing in your `var_dump`s:

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '/usr/lib/mcrypt-modes');
var_dump($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
var_dump($td);
```

It prints:

```
resource(4) of type (mcrypt)
resource(4) of type (Unknown)
```

Since you're seeing the same behavior (resource id remains the same, but loses its `mcrypt` association), it seems that you're closing your module resource at some point between initializing `$this->_td` and actually calling `mcrypt_generic_init`.